# Phoenix quick start doesn't work

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I deployed a HBASE 1.2.2 in pseudo distribution mode and was trying to add Phoenix for Hbase 1.2+ to see if it works. I followed the installation instruction on Phoenix website http://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html, but it doesn't as Hbase seems refuse the jdbc connection for some reason I don't know.

```
Setting property: [incremental, false]
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/phoenix/apache-phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-1.2-bin/phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-1.2-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
16/09/21 10:32:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/21 10:32:26 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: it seems that your hbase is not running. run ``jps`` to check if ``hbase`` started first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of HBase is not supported for Phoenix.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3116